# Parsing .txt files to a single .csv output

Tags: python

I am currently trying to parse 2 text files, then have a .csv output. One contains a list of path/file location, and the other is contains other info related to the path/file location.

1st text file contains (path.txt):

```
C:/Windows/System32/vssadmin.exe
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/google.com
```

2nd text file contains (filelist.txt):

```
-= List of files in hash: =-

$VAR1 = {
          'File' => [
                      {
                        'RootkitInfo' => 'Normal',
                        'FileVersionLabel' => '6.1.7600.16385',
                        'ProductVersion' => '6.1.7601.17514',
                        'Path' => 'C:/Windows/System32/vssadmin.exe',
                        'Signer' => 'Microsoft Windows',
                        'Size' => '210944',
                        'SHA1' => 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'
                        },
                        {
                        'RootkitInfo' => 'Normal',
                        'FileVersionLabel' => '6.1.7600.16385',
                        'ProductVersion' => '6.1.7601.17514',
                        'Path' => 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/steam.exe',
                        'Signer' => 'Valve Inc.',
                        'Size' => '300944',
                        'SHA1' => 'cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b65d94'
                        },
                        {
                        'RootkitInfo' => 'Normal',
                        'FileVersionLabel' => '6.1.7600.16385',
                        'ProductVersion' => '6.1.7601.17514',
                        'Path' => 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/google.com',
                        'Signer' => 'Valve Inc.',
                        'Size' => '300944',
                        'SHA1' => 'cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b78987'
                        },
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    ]
          }
```

---

How do I go about having a .csv output containing the path of the file with its corresponding hash value? Also, in case I would like to add additional column/info corresponding to the path?

Sample table output:

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>File Path</th>
        <th>Hash Value</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C:/Windows/System32/vssadmin.exe</td>
        <td>da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/google.com</td>
        <td>cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b78987</td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't show own effort and is too broad. It contains at least: parsing of PHP data definition, joining the data from two sources and formatting as HTML output.

Comment: @MichaelButscher the html is just for display purposes

Comment: The second file is not a `.txt` and will require fairly more effort to parse, since it doesn't nicely evaluate into a `dict` or other data structure. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct regex pattern that matches what you are looking for

```
pattern = r"""{.*?(C:/Windows/System32/vssadmin.exe).*?'SHA1' => '([^']*)'.*?}"""
```

To use it with multiple file names in a loop turn that pattern into a *format string*.

```
fmt = r"""{{.*?({}).*?'SHA1' => '([^']*)'.*?}}"""
```

Something like this:

```
import re
with open('filelist.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
with open('path.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pattern = fmt.format(line.strip())
        m = re.search(pattern, s, flags=re.DOTALL)
        if m:
            print(m.groups())
        else:
            print('no match for', fname)
```

---

It's a little inefficient and depends on the contents of the files to be exactly like you represented - like capitalization being the same.

---

Or without regular expressions: iterate over the lines of `filelist.txt`; find the `Path` line; extract the path with a slice, see if it is a path from `path.txt`; find the very next `SHA1` line; extract the hash with a slice.  This relies on the position of the two lines relative to each other and the position of the characters in each line. This will probably be more efficient.

```
with open('path.txt') as f:
    fnames = set(line.strip() for line in f)
with open('filelist.text') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("'Path'") and line[11:-2] in fnames:
            name = line[11:-2]
            while not line.startswith("'SHA1'"):
                line = next(f)
                line = line.strip()
            print((name, line[11:-2]))
```

This one also assumes the text files are as you represented them.

Answer (score 1):

To parse the alleged second `.txt` (of which it is not), you will need to re-structure it so that it looks like a normal python data structure. It's pretty close, and there are ways to coerce it to look like one:

```py
import ast

contents = "" # this will be to hold the read contents of that file
filestart = False 

with open('filelist.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if not filestart and not line.startswith("$VAR"):
            continue
        elif line.startswith("$VAR"):
            contents+="{" # start the dictionary
            filestart = True # to kill the first if statement
        else:
            contents += line # fill out with rest of file


# create dictionary, we use ast here because json will fail
result = ast.literal_eval(contents.replace("=>", ":"))

# {'File': [{'RootkitInfo': 'Normal', 'FileVersionLabel': '6.1.7600.16385', 'ProductVersion': '6.1.7601.17514', 'Path': 'C:/Windows/System32/vssadmin.exe', 'Signer': 'Microsoft Windows', 'Size': '210944', 'SHA1': 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'}, {'RootkitInfo': 'Normal', 'FileVersionLabel': '6.1.7600.16385', 'ProductVersion': '6.1.7601.17514', 'Path': 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/steam.exe', 'Signer': 'Valve Inc.', 'Size': '300944', 'SHA1': 'cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b65d94'}, {'RootkitInfo': 'Normal', 'FileVersionLabel': '6.1.7600.16385', 'ProductVersion': '6.1.7601.17514', 'Path': 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/google.com', 'Signer': 'Valve Inc.', 'Size': '300944', 'SHA1': 'cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b78987'}]}

files = result["File"] # get your list from here
```

Now that it's in a tolerable format, I'd convert it to a dict of `file: hash` key-value pairs for easy lookup against your other file

```py
files_dict = {file['Path']: file['SHA1'] for file in files}

# now grab your other file, and lookups should be quite simple

with open("path.txt") as fh:
    results = [f"{filepath.strip()}, {files_dict.get(filepath.strip())}" for filepath in fh]

# Now you can put that to a csv
with open("paths.csv", "w") as fh:
    fh.write('File Path,  Hash Value') # write the header
    fh.write('\n'.join(results))
```

There are better ways to do this, but that could be left as an exercise to the reader